# How can I disable takefocus for a parent and all of its children?

Tags: python, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit

I can write `widget.configure(takefocus=False)` for a widget to achieve what I want. But is there a way I can easily disable focusing on a parent widget and all of its children, rather than iterating through every child and disabling one by one?

Here's an example:

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


class BasicOperations(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        operations = "+-*/"
        self.buttons = list()
        for op in operations:
            self.buttons.append(tk.Button(self, text=op))
        #configure the geometry
        for i in range(len(self.buttons)):
            self.buttons[i].grid()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    basic_ops = BasicOperations(root)
    basic_ops.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

I tried calling `self.configure(takefocus=False)` inside `__init__` but it didn't disable focus take for the buttons under it.

Comment: Why not `for button in self.buttons:` when setting up the `command` and layout geometry?

Comment: @DonalFellows that's what I'd initially do but wondered if there was a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Focus decisions are *not* enforced recursively like that, since it is quite normal for containing widgets (typically frames) to not take focus even when their contained widgets do take focus. However, the `takefocus` attribute doesn't need to be a static thing; it can be set to a callable that returns a boolean, so that any time a focus traversal decision is taken, the callable takes the decision about whether the current widget should have focus given to it. This means that all you have to do is to provide a callable that returns a value from a variable that is common across the group of interest.

You have a convenient class which provides a sensible scope, so a method of the class instance makes a perfect callable.

```
try:                        # In order to be able to import tkinter for
    import tkinter as tk    # either in python 2 or in python 3
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


class BasicOperations(tk.Frame):
    def _take_focus_handler(self):
        return self._group_focusable

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self._group_focusable = True
        operations = "+-*/"
        self.buttons = list()
        for op in operations:
            self.buttons.append(tk.Button(self, text=op,
                                        takefocus=self._take_focus_handler))
        #configure the geometry
        for i in range(len(self.buttons)):
            self.buttons[i].grid()

    def set_group_focusable(self, value=True):
        self._group_focusable = value
        # Note that you might also want to defocus the widgets if the focus is
        # already in the group, but you didn't ask for that...


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    basic_ops = BasicOperations(root)
    basic_ops.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I updated my question for readability improvement(s), and co-edited your answer to reflect better to it. It seems the code you've provided raises error(s) when a butten gets focus as apparently `takefocus` calls its reference with one positional argument. I'd fix this replacing method definition to `def _take_focus_handler(self, focused_widget_name=None):`, but it's your answer so I didn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can do the solution in 2 steps:

1. Disable `takefocus` for the parent widget.
2. Loop over the [children](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.winfo_children-method) of that parent widget and disable `takefocus` for each one of them:

   ```
   for child in self.winfo_children():
       child.configure(takefocus=False)
   ```

Comment: This _is_ iteration though.